# Package Jason file issue

Tags: npm-scripts

We had given a task for react native. in that we have one package.jason file. When we executing that jason file  then we are getting some error. We are not sure about why that error coming. Part rt of package jason  i.e. what where we getting error for that code is

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export PORT=8000 && node scripts/start.js",
    "test": "nightwatch",
    "ci": "rm -rf ./report/* && ((start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test) &&  mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml ) || mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml"
  },
```

Any issue with it as we getting error as -

```
> rm -rf ./report/* && ((start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test) &&  mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml ) || mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml

internal/util.js:214
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:214:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projects/challenge/node_modules/start-server-and-test/node_modules/get-stream/index.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projects/challenge/node_modules/start-server-and-test/node_modules/execa/lib/stream.js:3:19)
mv: cannot stat './report/*': No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! contact@0.1.0 ci: `rm -rf ./report/* && ((start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test) &&  mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml ) || mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no rm in npm. You need to use an external library for that functionality, such as https://github.com/shelljs/shx.

Install the package:

> npm install shx --save-dev

Add the prefix 'shx' on your unix command:

> "ci": "shx rm -rf ./report/* && ((start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test) &&  shx mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml ) || shx mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml"

Comment: can we use   ```"ci": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test"```

Comment: still same issue ```mv: no such file or directory: ./report/*

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! contact@0.1.0 ci: `shx rm -rf ./report/* && ((start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test) && shx mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml ) || shx mv ./report/* ./report/unit.xml`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the contact@0.1.0 ci script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```

Comment: It's a different error. It's telling you that ./report/* doesn't exist. If is in the same folder try to replace it with /report. There is no need of the asterisk.

Comment: can we use "ci": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:8000 test" –

Comment: what is start-server-and-test?